# Access crosstab formula field in another crosstab column?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

How to access crosstab formula field in another column? I have report like with Dues & total both formula fields:

```
Amount  Dues(Done by a Formula)   Total (Done by a Formula)
------ ------------------------- ---------------------------
 500              20 %                  someAmount
```

Formula for Dues:

```
WhileReadingRecords;
       numberVar due:={Command.SomeField)/100;
        due
```

Formula for Total:

```
WhileReadingRecords;
         numberVar total:= {Command.Amount} - due;
         total
```

How do I access due field inside the second formula for each row of record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just use `{@FormulaName}` (See image below)
2. Crystal syntax is very simple for simple formulas.  For your sample formulas, you don't need to declare variables or use WhileReadingRecords. (Both have their uses, but for your sample formulas, they are unneeded).  Again, see the image below for an example.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Thanks PowerUser. The screen shot helped a lot.